# How do you retrieve an object from the ObjectStoreModule in Mule using Java?

Tags: mule

I have an ObjectStoreModule configured to store some JSON as a string.  According to the spec (http://mulesoft.github.io/mule-module-objectstore/java/org/mule/modules/ObjectStoreModule.html), I expect to be able to call retrieve and get a copy of the object I stored.  However, when I try this, I seem to only get the key returned and not the object itself...

Here is about what my code looks like at the moment.

```
ObjectStoreModule objectStore = (ObjectStoreModule) eventContext.getMuleContext().getRegistry().lookupObject("sourceConfigStore");

objectStore.store("KEY", jsonAsString, true);

System.out.println((String)objectStore.retrieve("sourceConfigStore", "KEY", null, null, eventContext.getMessage()))
```

At the moment, this only prints out "KEY" and not the variable named jsonAsString.  I realize that there are other input parameters to the retrieve method that will designate a mule message property to assign the retrieved object to, but I want to be able to interact with this store from within java without the extra step of assigning these values to mule message properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not passing in the proper parameters to the retrieve() method of the ObjectStoreModule.  The first is the "key" and the second is a default value to be returned if the key is not found.  I was passing in the name of the store and the key as the default, which is why the returned value was the key, since the name of the store could not be found as a key in the store itself....  woops.